# TLS 1.0 not supported between client and server

Tags: c#-4.0, ssl, https

I am having problems trying to get a Https connection between a desktop fat client application and a server.

After much searching I found on server system logs, the following error message, "An TLS1.0 connection was received from a remote client application , but none of the cipher suites supported by the client are supported the server. The SSL connection request has failed."

Checking in Internet explorer the connection fails with the same error message when I type in the https address. However, if I type in the address in Chrome or in Firefox the connection works and I get a successful json response. In Wireshark I note that the number of cipher algorithms being presented by IE is a lot less than Firefox and chrome.

Is there a way to fix this problem? The application I have to work with is an existing app, and needs to be https in order to link with a new restful service from a new application.

I have been banging on with this problem for a few days and run out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You have a cipher suite mismatch.

The server and client (browser) will attempt to agree on a cipher suite. In your case, it sounds like Internet Explorer  and .NET are not using a cipher suite that the server supports.

Both Internet Explorer and the .NET Framework use [SChannel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380123(v=vs.85).aspx) under the covers to make HTTPS connections. More specifically, the .NET Framework classes that are part of the BCL. It is entirely possible to re-implement SSL/TLS and not use SChannel.

Without knowing what the actual cipher suites are by both the client and server, it's hard to say.

SChannel is configurable by Group Policy to tune which cipher suites are enabled. Not that SChannel is not capable of doing every cipher suite possible that servers may support. This would need to be applied the desktops where the thick client runs.

Alternatively you can configure the server to accept cipher suites that your clients support. How to do that depends on your web server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and you have written interests me. The application runs in 4.0 of .net and is calling an iis server on Windows server 2008 r2. The server and desktops are supported by our helpdesk. I know they may set some gpo setting which has affected ie and subsequently the fat client. Is there any more information you can give on giving the iis server to accept all cipher suites?

Comment: Certificates were generated using visual studio 2010 makecert utility